# Monkeyrunner == I have to check whether my script is working fine or not

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I have been using Monkey runner to automate applications. My script is working fine . But following are the constraints.

1. While running complete script application is crashing and showing Force Close.
2. How to check command is working fine.

I tried using getproperty(). It is not getting updated as and when application is working.

Please reply.

Thanks is Advance

Answer (score 0):

To check that my program worked when using monkeyrunner I normally save the log and write a python program that looks over it once my monkeyrunner script is finished working.

If you want to put more work into things you could also use python's subprocess module and adb to look at the log while your program runs.